# Redirect 301 effective only some urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla2.5

For some reason I am suddenly having trouble getting my Redirect 301s to work. The .htaccess file is below. I have pasted only the 1st 10 Redirect 301 commmands but there are over 100.

The 301 Redirects all have the same format, but the first six listed have no effect. The last four (followed by "******") operate as expected. I can see no explanation.

Any ideas?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

########## Begin - Custom redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.caringcompanion\.net [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://caringcompanion.net/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

Redirect 301 /homecare/10-caring-companion/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=89&Itemid=75 http://www.caringcompanion.net/concord-ma

Redirect 301 /homecare/10-caring-companion/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=94&Itemid=75 http://caringcompanion.net/cambridge-ma

Redirect 301 /homecare/10-caring-companion/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=94&Itemid=74 http://caringcompanion.net/cambridge-ma

Redirect 301 /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=94:cambridge-ma-home-care-elderly-caregivers&catid=38:cambridge&Itemid=74 http://caringcompanion.net/cambridge-ma

Redirect 301 /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=93:acton-ma-home-care-elderly-caregivers&catid=34:acton&Itemid=70 http://caringcompanion.net/acton-ma

Redirect 301 /homecare/10-caring-companion/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=93&Itemid=70 http://caringcompanion.net/acton-ma

Redirect 301 /homecare-ma/ma/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=52&Itemid=158 http://caringcompanion.net/homecare-massachuetts-maine-new-hampshire

Redirect 301 /tag/71-biophilia http://caringcompanion.net/services/client-care-coordinators  ***********

Redirect 301 /ccc-copyright-notice/73-caring-companion/services/127-alzheimers-dementia-services http://caringcompanion.net/services/alzheimers-dementia   *********

Redirect 301 /index.php/component/content/article/73-caring-companion/services/127-alzheimers-dementia-services http://caringcompanion.net/services/alzheimers-dementia  ******

Redirect 301 /jblog/118-alzheimers-dementia http://caringcompanion.net/services/alzheimers-dementia   ***********************
```

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is that you cannot match against the query string in the pattern of a `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` statement. The statement:

```
Redirect 301 /homecare/10-caring-companion/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=89&Itemid=75 http://www.caringcompanion.net/concord-ma
```

Actually tries to match against this URI:

```
/homecare/10-caring-companion/index.php%3Foption=com_content%26view=article%26id=89%26Itemid=75
```

And not the query string (everything after the `?`). You need to use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var from mod_rewrite to match against that. So something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=89&Itemid=75$ 
RewriteRule ^/?homecare/10-caring-companion/index\.php$ http://caringcompanion.net/concord-ma [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=94&Itemid=75$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=94&Itemid=74$
RewriteRule ^/?homecare/10-caring-companion/index\.php$ http://caringcompanion.net/cambridge-ma [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=94:cambridge-ma-home-care-elderly-caregivers&catid=38:cambridge&Itemid=74$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ http://caringcompanion.net/cambridge-ma [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=93:acton-ma-home-care-elderly-caregivers&catid=34:acton&Itemid=70$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ http://caringcompanion.net/action-ma [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=93&Itemid=70$ 
RewriteRule ^/?homecare/10-caring-companion/index\.php$ http://caringcompanion.net/action-ma [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=52&Itemid=158$
RewriteRule ^/?homecare-ma/ma/index.php$ http://caringcompanion.net/homecare-massachuetts-maine-new-hampshire [L,R=301]
```

Depending on what other `Redirect`'s you have, you could find that you're getting redirected to unexpected URLs that you didn't explicitly make. It's possible that the rewrite rules (mod_rewrite) and the redirects (mod_alias) are interfering with each other because the two modules get applied at different points of the URL-file mapping engine, and both modules could end up mangling the same URI. If that happens, you should stick to only using mod_rewrite for your redirects because you need the rewrite engine to match against the query string.

Comment: Jon, excellent thanks. In my case, I wanted to delete the query string entirely so I had to add '?' at the end of the substitute url to get the result I want and now it's perfect.